# remove unwanted values from csv file in python

Tags: python

I have a csv file that has some none values and I want the remove those columns which have all the none values.

```
Name class  marks1 marks2

A    10th   67     55
B    10th   None   None
C    10th   43     None
```

In the above table, I need to remove B because all marks are none and create a new table with the remaining student. and output I needed an updated csv file like this

```
Name class  marks1 marks2

A    10th   67     55
C    10th   43     None
```

I tried this:

```
import csv
lines = list()
with open('f_name', 'r') as readFile:
   reader = csv.reader(readFile)
   for row in reader:
       lines.append(row)
       #print(row[4:])
       if row[2:] == 'None':
       print(row)

with open(f_name, 'w') as writeFile:
    writer = csv.writer(writeFile)
    writer.writerows(lines)
```

Comment: It's pretty simple task (*Literally few lines of code*). The only suggestion is to not try "modify" existing file, better to save filtered table to new file.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I tried this   import csv
lines = list()
with open('f_name', 'r') as readFile:
    reader = csv.reader(readFile)
    for row in reader:
        lines.append(row)
        #print(row[4:])
        if row[2:] == 'None':
            print(row)

with open(f_name, 'w') as writeFile:
    writer = csv.writer(writeFile)
    writer.writerows(lines)

Comment: Add your code to question

Comment: You can open both files in single `with` block: `with open('f_name', 'r') as readFile, open(f_name, 'w') as writeFile:`, it will give you an opportunity to consume lines without storing whole file in memory. To check *3rd* and *4th* column you can use `if not (row[2] == 'None' and row[3] == 'None'): writer.writerow(row)`.

Answer (score 1):

you can filter the rows where neither mark1 and mark2 are null

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.read_csv('f_name')
df2=df1[~(pd.isnull(df1.marks1) & pd.isnull(df1.marks2))]
```

Comment: but I have large data

Comment: yes but this was an example `df2=df1[~(pd.isnull(df1.marks1) & pd.isnull(df1.marks2))]` will works in any data size.

Comment: I see now that you are not using pandas. I will update my answer teaching you how to do it with pandas

Comment: NaN is not a number so you cant verify if NaN is equal to NaN, but pandas understand that if a value is NaN than it is null

Comment: also as you can see by my code pandas is much simpler to use than csv. You don't need to create a reader and iterate over rows. It automatically reads a csv or excell file and converts it to a DataFrame object, where you can either iterate over rows or columns

Comment: ooh, actually in the above question I mentions just an example but my real data is large and contain some of the columns 'None' so I need to remove those rows

Comment: If you want that I will send my csv file

Comment: try to use my code and see if it works. If you don't have pandas you can open a prompt terminal and type `pip install pandas` it will works if you have pip installed

Answer (score 0):

`if row[2:] == 'None'` simply checks if the array slice is equal to a string, which of course it will never be.

```py
if any(x != 'None' for x in row[2:]):
```

loops over the array slice and checks if at least one element is not equal to the string `'None'`.

Of course, you will then want to `append` the line only if the condition is true.

More economically, read and write a single line at a time.

```py
import csv

with open('f_name', 'r') as readFile, open('f_name_new.csv', 'w') as writeFile:
   reader = csv.reader(readFile)
   writer = csv.writer(writeFile)
   for row in reader:
       if any(x != 'None' for x in row[2:]):
           writer.writerow(row)
```

You can't read and write the same file at the same time, so this uses a different name for the output file. If you read all the lines into memory, like in your original approach, you can overwrite the original file once you have all the data in memory, of course. The drawback is that you are restricted to files which will fit into memory; this tends to get slow for large files.

Comment: I'd use `any(x != 'None' for x in row[2:])`, cause `all()` have to consume whole generator while `any()` will stop on first truth value.